# `Missing = inserted for \ifnum` Error During Compilation

Tags: biblatex, errors, compiling

I know this question has been asked many times before. There are many similar questions but I failed to solve mine. During compilation, I'm getting the following error message:

```
./thesis.tex:41: Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   D
l.41 
     
./thesis.tex:41:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I‘m getting this error when I compile my LaTeX project like so:

```
latexmk -halt-on-error \
        -file-line-error \
        -no-shell-escape \
        -pdf \
        -output-directory=output \
        $(NAME_FILE)
```

The compilation happens inside a Docker container of Fedora 36. I‘ve installed `texlive-scheme-full` and `latexmk`. The funny thing is that line 41 within `thesis.tex` is an empty line.

You can find my full log message [here](https://zerobin.net/?7c567f6c1051d21a#X5Ylo7cM4kmZTaNhk8EhaXFNHxjtwT6EyTQwO5q7+fU=).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clue is

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex DATE vVERSION programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
```

which should look more like

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2022/02/02 v3.17 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
```

which an actual date instead of `DATE` and a version number instead of `VERSION`.

Your `biblatex.sty` is faulty. This is a known packaging issue with Fedora 36 that has been reported and should have been resolved a few weeks ago. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1218 and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2065453. Update your system thoroughly and rebuild.

Comment: Prior to this question, I did a docker rebuild thinking there could be something wrong with the setup. That didn't work. After your answer, I realised I forgot to relaunch my new container from that new build. My clumsiness. Thanks!